# Migrating from .Net 4 to 5 changes the build task behavior and does not include `intermediate output` generated resources into the dll

Tags: c#, migration, hlsl, msbuild-task, .net-5

I'm migrating an `WPF` app from `.Net Framework 4` to `.Net 5`.
That app rely on a (referenced project) library that allows some custom hlsl effects.
To compile `hlsl` files on the fly into `ps` files and include them in the generated `dll` file, i'm using: [this build task](http://aarononeal.info/hlsl-shader-build-task-with-visual-studio-integration/).

This is working flawlessly using .Net Framework 4 using that `csproj` file (of the effect library project):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <UsingTask TaskName="ShaderBuildTask.PixelShaderCompile" AssemblyName="ShaderBuildTask, Version=1.0.3072.18169, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=44e467d1687af125" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>9.0.21022</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{22A99010-4E29-47AA-994E-6CCE9C28D45F}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>Comics.Effects</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Comics.Effects</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <FileUpgradeFlags>
    </FileUpgradeFlags>
    <OldToolsVersion>3.5</OldToolsVersion>
    <UpgradeBackupLocation />
    <PublishUrl>publish\</PublishUrl>
    <Install>true</Install>
    <InstallFrom>Disk</InstallFrom>
    <UpdateEnabled>false</UpdateEnabled>
    <UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
    <UpdateInterval>7</UpdateInterval>
    <UpdateIntervalUnits>Days</UpdateIntervalUnits>
    <UpdatePeriodically>false</UpdatePeriodically>
    <UpdateRequired>false</UpdateRequired>
    <MapFileExtensions>true</MapFileExtensions>
    <ApplicationRevision>0</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>1.0.0.%2a</ApplicationVersion>
    <IsWebBootstrapper>false</IsWebBootstrapper>
    <UseApplicationTrust>false</UseApplicationTrust>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>true</BootstrapperEnabled>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\x64\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64'">
    <OutputPath>bin\x64\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86'">
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core">
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq">
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions">
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="WindowsBase">
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="PresentationCore">
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="PresentationFramework">
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="DenoiseEffect.cs" />
    <Compile Include="BilateralEffect.cs" />
    <Compile Include="UnsharpEffect.cs" />
    <Compile Include="AdjustEffect.cs">
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="EffectLibrary.cs">
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <PixelShader Include="AdjustEffect.fx" />
    <PixelShader Include="BilateralEffect.fx">
      <ShaderModel>3_0</ShaderModel>
    </PixelShader>
    <Service Include="{94E38DFF-614B-4cbd-B67C-F211BB35CE8B}" />
    <PixelShader Include="UnsharpEffect.fx">
      <ShaderModel>3_0</ShaderModel>
    </PixelShader>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1</ProductName>
      <Install>true</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)'=='true'">
    <AvailableItemName Include="VertexShader">
      <Visible>false</Visible>
    </AvailableItemName>
    <AvailableItemName Include="PixelShader">
      <Visible>false</Visible>
    </AvailableItemName>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PixelShader Include="DenoiseEffect.fx" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <UsingTask TaskName="ShaderBuildTask.ShaderCompile" AssemblyName="ShaderBuildTask, Version=1.0.3072.18169, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=44e467d1687af125" />
  <Target Name="VertexShaderCompile" Condition="'@(VertexShader)' != '' " BeforeTargets="Build">
    <ShaderCompile Sources="@(VertexShader)" ShaderProfile="vs_3_0" IntermediateOutputPath="$(IntermediateOutputPath)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Outputs" ItemName="Resource" />
    </ShaderCompile>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="PixelShaderCompile" Condition="'@(PixelShader)' != '' " BeforeTargets="Build">
    <ShaderCompile Sources="@(PixelShader)" ShaderProfile="ps_3_0" IntermediateOutputPath="$(IntermediateOutputPath)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Outputs" ItemName="Resource" />
    </ShaderCompile>
  </Target>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PrepareResourcesDependsOn>VertexShaderCompile;PixelShaderCompile;$(PrepareResourcesDependsOn)</PrepareResourcesDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

But after migrating to .Net 5 the solution builds fine, the `ps` files are compiled into the `obj` directory, but the `ps` files aren't included into the `dll`, thus, making the `wpf` app launch and crash right after (as it needs the `ps` files).

Here is the new migrated `csproj` file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
  <UsingTask TaskName="ShaderBuildTask.ShaderCompile" AssemblyName="ShaderBuildTask, Version=1.0.3072.18169, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=44e467d1687af125" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <EnableDefaultCompileItems>false</EnableDefaultCompileItems>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="DenoiseEffect.cs" />
    <Compile Include="BilateralEffect.cs" />
    <Compile Include="UnsharpEffect.cs" />
    <Compile Include="AdjustEffect.cs">
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="EffectLibrary.cs">
    </Compile>

    <PixelShader Include="AdjustEffect.fx">
      <ShaderModel>2_0</ShaderModel>
    </PixelShader>
    <PixelShader Include="BilateralEffect.fx">
      <ShaderModel>3_0</ShaderModel>
    </PixelShader>
    <PixelShader Include="UnsharpEffect.fx">
      <ShaderModel>3_0</ShaderModel>
    </PixelShader>
    <PixelShader Include="DenoiseEffect.fx" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <UsingTask TaskName="ShaderBuildTask.ShaderCompile" AssemblyName="ShaderBuildTask, Version=1.0.3072.18169, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=44e467d1687af125" />

  <Target Name="VertexShaderCompile" Condition="'@(VertexShader)' != '' " BeforeTargets="Build">
    <ShaderCompile Sources="@(VertexShader)" ShaderProfile="vs_3_0" IntermediateOutputPath="$(IntermediateOutputPath)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Outputs" ItemName="Resource" />
    </ShaderCompile>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="PixelShaderCompile" Condition="'@(PixelShader)' != '' " BeforeTargets="Build">
    <ShaderCompile Sources="@(PixelShader)" ShaderProfile="ps_3_0" IntermediateOutputPath="$(IntermediateOutputPath)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Outputs" ItemName="Resource" />
    </ShaderCompile>
  </Target>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <PrepareResourcesDependsOn>VertexShaderCompile;PixelShaderCompile;$(PrepareResourcesDependsOn)</PrepareResourcesDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

The only differences are the migration to .Net 5 and the removing of the `run configurations` for simplicity. Nothing else on the project has been modified.